# Hiking from Tillamook Trailhead to Indian Beach Trailhead

Tags: usa, hiking, walking, oregon

If I start hiking at [Tillamook Head](https://goo.gl/maps/1pigUHk1tgQ1djzU9) (Seaside, OR), will I be able to [Indian Beach Trailhead](https://goo.gl/maps/v6MWNXcB5mvcJcsg8) (Cannon Beach, OR)?  If so, is it feasible (or are there some hindrances, like the trail turns into a bog after a rainy weather, etc.)? Further, will I be able to walk along Ecola State Park Rd. to Cannon Beach (e.g. to Les Shirley Park), or is that a car-only road?

Update: according to [this](https://www.oregonhikers.org/field_guide/Tillamook_Head_Traverse_Hike), the answer to my first question seems to be yes:

> This traverse hike, a designated National Recreation Trail and also part of the Oregon Coast Trail, can be shuttled by beginning at either the Indian Beach Trailhead in Ecola State Park, just north of Cannon Beach, or the Tillamook Head Trailhead, although the latter is a better choice if you're doing this as a 12.6 mile out and back trip because you don't have to pay the state parks day use fee. The Tillamook Head Trailhead is just south of Seaside.

Comment: A peek using street view as far up Ecola State Park Rd as Google shows indicates a pretty narrow road with no shoulder. However, there likely isn't a ton of traffic, so if you keep a sharp eye out for traffic and get off the road in a timely fashion you are likely OK. It also might be easy to get a lift into town from other hikers leaving the trailhead.

Comment: Please accept the answer which you think is the most useful, your own answer included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick check of the segment explorer in Strava shows that many people frequently run on the trails between Tillamook Head and Indian Beach Trailhead, and they also frequently run the length of Ecola State Park Road. In fact it's popular with both runners and cyclists.

For the trail segment, do note that you will gain about 1,000 feet of elevation, and there are switchbacks/moderately rough terrain. Runners generally average 2-3 minutes/mile slower than their usual city-running average when running this particular route.

For the road segment, just stay on the left and wear something visible. People drive slowly.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully walked from Les Shirley Park all the way to Tillamook Head (through the Indian Beach Trail, then through the coastal part of the Clatsop Loop Trail, and through the Hikers Camp) this December. It was raining the day before my hike and earlier that week, and the trails were muddy and slippery, but nothing unpassable. I've only encountered a couple of cars on Ecola State Park Rd. (in the morning).